# why can't pandas sort openai embeddings by similarities in .csv files

Tags: python, numpy, openai-api

The following code:

```
input_datapath = "data/wiki_data_embeddings.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_datapath)

question = "What temperature is a high fever?"
question_vector = get_embedding(question, engine=embedding_model)

df["similarities"] = df['embedding'].apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, question_vector))
df = df.sort_values("similarities", ascending=False).head(5)
print(df)
```

has the following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U34386'), dtype('<U23')) -> None
```

My csv file contains a column called 'embedding' which contains the vector representations of the content text of wikipedia articles.  I am trying to create a chatGPT embedded search model by converting the question into a vector and cross checking it with the embeddings in the csv file.  I do not know how to fix the following error as everything else in my file is currently working and this seems to be an issue with numpy itself. Any help that can be provided will be much appreciated.

```
input_datapath = "data/wiki_data_embeddings.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_datapath)

question = "What temperature is a high fever?"
question_vector = get_embedding(question, engine=embedding_model)

df["similarities"] = df['embedding'].apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, question_vector))
df = df.sort_values("similarities", ascending=False).head(5)
print(df)
```

Comment: The error says it can't multiply two strings  `(dtype('<U34386'), dtype('<U23'))`.  `U` for unicode, and the number is the length.  My guess is that your `df`, as loaded from the csv, contains strings in the column(s), not some sort of array or list or what ever.  I suggest looking both at the csv, and df (though pandas df display does not adequately distinguish between strings and lists.  In any case, make sure you understand what both the csv and frame contain.  Don't make assumptions.  Verify!